# Format duration time

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have got two timestamps in milliseconds. I calculate duration between them, but the result has also milliseconds value, but I want just second.

First timestamp,

> 1519077042063

Second timestamp

> 1519077045841

Result after XSLT

> 3.778

```
xs:dateTime(1519077045841)-xs:dateTime(1519077042063))
```

Wanted result

> 3

EDIT

Here is how i calculate the dateTime from timestamp.

```
<xsl:variable name="start" select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + 1519077042063 * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>

<xsl:variable name="stop" select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + 1519077045841 * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
```

Then I calculate a duration from start and stop which is PT3.778S and I want just 3. It is possible to do it?

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime($stop)-xs:dateTime($start))"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you could create an `xs:dateTime` directly from the timestamp value as you show with `xs:dateTime(1519077045841)-xs:dateTime(1519077042063)` but if you substract two `xs:dateTime`s you get a duration and you can then extract the `seconds-from-duration` and call the `floor` function on it: `floor(seconds-from-duration($dateTime1 - $dateTime2))`.

So for your sample in the edit

```
   <xsl:variable name="start" select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + 1519077042063 * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
   <xsl:variable name="stop" select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + 1519077045841 * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
   <xsl:value-of select="floor(seconds-from-duration($stop - $start))"/>
```

gives `3`: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nbUY4ks

Comment: I added more information about my question to EDIT section.

Comment: @J.Hradek, I have added a snippet using your two variables.

Comment: Yes it works. And what if I will have two timestamps and duration between them will be in result something like this `13 days 23 hours 30 minutes 24.342 seconds`, but I want just `13 days 23 hours 30 minutes 24 seconds`?

Comment: Convert the duration to a number by dividing by a unit duration, e.g. PT1S, then do any rounding or other manipulation you want on the number, then convert back to a duration by multiplying by the unit duration.